# how to add two millisecond column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have table as shown below

```
gid code time  qid
 1 123  08:108 15
 1 145  11:012 15
 1 145  11:216 16
 1 123  12:102 16
```

Now U want to group the 'gid' and add the two time with same code column (ex: i am taking 123, calculating the time (08:108+12:102)/2. Divided by '2' because code 123 appears two time,if it appears three time then divided by 3 this should be dynamic.

I want the result should be

```
gid code time   
1   123  10:105 
1   145  11:114
```

i tried using this query

SELECT sum(time) FROM results group by code; // result in integer values

and SELECT timestamp(sum(time)) FROM results group by code; // result is null

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.can you please add What you have tried so far ?

Comment: What column type is your `time` column?

Comment: Yes, time column type is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `time` field does not look like it is of the type `TIME`. A TIME field is in the format `HH:MM:SS` and doesn't allow to store milliseconds. The [MySQL Documentation states that trailing fractions of seconds are allowed in date and time values, but are discarded and not stored](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Your `time` field looks like it is a varchar and while you can use functions like `SUM()` or `AVG()` on that, your notation `seconds:milliseconds` is wrong.

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT code,AVG(REPLACE(time,':','.')) FROM results group by code
```

This replaces the `:` in your value with `.`, creating a float number `AVG()` can handle correctly.

The result:

```
code    AVG(REPLACE(time,':','.'))
123     10.105
145     11.114
```

Of course this will create more operations on the SQL server. The best way would be to change your column definition to `FLOAT` and store your seconds and milliseconds as a float:

```
code    time
123     8.108
145     11.012
145     11.216
123     12.102
```

The result of `SELECT code,AVG(time) FROM results GROUP BY code`:

```
code    AVG(time)
123     10.1050000190735
145     11.1139998435974
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `avg` aggregate function on a `time` column - you'd just need to convert it back to `time` when you're done, and use `time_format` if the default format doesn't suit you:

```
SELECT   gid, code, TIME_FORMAT(TIME(AVG(`time`)), '%H-%i.%f')
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY gid, code
```

Comment: thank lot for answering. gid code TIME(AVG(`time`))
1   123  00:00:10
1   145  00:00:11 still it is not showing milliseconds. I want to display milliseconds also

Comment: @KaifKhan I edited my answer to call `time_format` and display microseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. The query given by @Gerald Schneider is perfect match to my result. Thanks once again @ Mr Mureinik